# Poor error handling: Throw inside Finally

Tags: java, error-handling

I have the following code which I am running through fortify. Why it gets marked for poor error handling, throw inside finally?

```
private String getResourceContent(String fileName) throws IOException {

    try (InputStream resource = ErrorResource.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
        return new String(resource.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        throw new ErrorDescriptorException(
                String.format("Error loading Error description data from Resource file [%s].", fileName), n);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ErrorDescriptorException`?

Comment: class ErrorDescriptorException extends RuntimeException

Answer (score 5):

[`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) throws a `NullPointerException` if the given name is null, something you can easily check. [`InputStream.readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--) does not throw a `NullPointerException`, and neither does instatiating the String.

So basically, the null exception will happen if and only if `fileName` is null, or if the resource is not found and therefore resource is null; you can easily check both without catching an exception:

```java
private String getResourceContent(String fileName) throws IOException {
    if (fileName == null) {
        // now what?
    }
    try (InputStream resource = ErrorResource.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
        if (resource == null) {
            // now what?
        }
        return new String(resource.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

The question now is what you want to do if `fileName` or `resource` is null. This depends on how you want your function to be used; in my opinion, you should expect the user to give a file name that is not null, so throw a `NullPointerException` if that is not the case. In the `resource` case, you could use your custom exception for that.

Now, what if `readAllBytes()` throws an exception? You can either let it propagate to the caller (like it's happening now) or use `ErrorDescriptorException` as a wrapper (but maybe this makes fortify complain again):

```java
private String getResourceContent(String fileName) throws ErrorDescriptorException {
    if (fileName == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    try (InputStream resource = ErrorResource.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
        if (resource == null) {
            throw new ErrorDescriptorException(
                String.format("Error loading Error description data from Resource file [%s].", fileName));
        }
        return new String(resource.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
    catch (IOException | OutOfMemoryException e) {
        throw new ErrorDescriptorException(
                String.format("Error loading Error description data from Resource file [%s].", fileName), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: NPE can also be there at ErrorResource.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName). ErrorResource.classLoader can be null if loaded by bootstrap classloader.

Comment: True, you should add a case for that one too. The idea here is that catching `NullPointerException` is *generally* a bad idea as you can usually just check if `== null`